# Не перерисовывается окно :(

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, masm32, masm

Почему у меня не перерисовывается окно, то есть если я начну изменять его размеры то белый фон не будет возвращаться, а будет какой-то чёрный? И ещё если не сложно, подскажите как сделать фон например тёмно-зелёный? Я как понял `COLOR_BACKGROUND-1` = белый, `COLOR_BACKGROUND` = серый, `COLOR_BACKGROUND+1` = чёрный.

[image: Скрин]

Вот мой код :

```
      .486                      ; create 32 bit code
      .model flat, stdcall      ; 32 bit memory model
      option casemap :none      ; case sensitive

      include \masm32\include\windows.inc
      include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
      include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc
      include \masm32\include\user32.inc
      include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
      include \masm32\include\Comctl32.inc
      include \masm32\include\comdlg32.inc
      include \masm32\include\shell32.inc
      include \masm32\include\oleaut32.inc
      include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
      include \masm32\include\dialogs.inc
      include \masm32\macros\macros.asm

      includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\Comctl32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\comdlg32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\shell32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\oleaut32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
     Main   PROTO  

.data?
hIcon           Dd ?
hBrush         Dd ?
hCursor       Dd ?
hImage        Dd ?
hInstance    Dd ?

.data
wc      WNDCLASS <?>
newhwnd dd 0
szTitleName     db 'Window Application',0
msg     MONMSGSTRUCT <?> ;  структура сообщения
szClassName     db 'ASMCLASS32',0

.code

start:
  mov hInstance, FUNC(GetModuleHandle,NULL) 
  mov    hIcon, FUNC(LoadIcon, hInstance, 100)
  mov    hCursor, FUNC(LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW)
  mov    hBrush, FUNC(GetSysColorBrush, COLOR_APPWORKSPACE)

  Mov [wc.style], CS_HREDRAW+CS_VREDRAW+CS_GLOBALCLASS
Mov [wc.lpfnWndProc], offset WndProc 
Mov [wc.cbClsExtra], 0
Mov [wc.cbWndExtra], 0
Mov eax, [hInstance]
Mov [wc.hInstance], eax
Invoke LoadIcon,0,IDI_APPLICATION
Mov [wc.hIcon], eax 
Invoke LoadCursorA,0,IDC_ARROW
Mov [wc.hCursor], eax
Mov [wc.hbrBackground], COLOR_BACKGROUND-1
Mov dword ptr [wc.lpszMenuName], 0
Mov dword ptr [wc.lpszClassName], offset szClassName
Invoke RegisterClassA,offset wc

Push 0
Push [hInstance] ; дескриптор
Push 0
Push 0
Push 600 ; высота
Push 700 ; ширина
Push CW_USEDEFAULT ; y
Push CW_USEDEFAULT ; x
Push WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW ; стиль
Push offset szTitleName ; заголовок окна
Push offset szClassName ; имя класса
Push 0 ; дополнительный стиль
Call CreateWindowEx ; создаём окно


mov [newhwnd], eax
invoke ShowWindow,[newhwnd],SW_SHOWNORMAL;  
invoke UpdateWindow, [newhwnd];
msg_loop:
invoke GetMessage,offset msg, 0,0,0 
cmp ax, 0
je end_loop     
invoke TranslateMessage, offset msg 
invoke DispatchMessage, offset msg
jmp msg_loop
end_loop:
 invoke ExitProcess,eax


WndProc proc uses ebx edi esi, hwnd:DWORD, wmsg:DWORD, wparam:DWORD, lparam:DWORD

Cmp [wmsg], WM_DESTROY
Je wmdestroy
Cmp [wmsg], WM_KEYDOWN
Je wmkeydown
Invoke DefWindowProcA,[hwnd],[wmsg],[wparam],[lparam]
    ; вызываем стандартный обработчик сообщений
Jmp finish
wmkeydown:
cmp [wparam], VK_ESCAPE
je wmdestroy; если нажата клавиша Escape то выход
jmp finish
wmdestroy:
invoke PostQuitMessage, 0
invoke ExitProcess, 0   ; выход
finish: 
ret
WndProc endp
End start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COLOR_BACKGROUND-1` это `COLOR_SCROLLBAR`. Это явно не то, что вам нужно. К тому же, по какой-то причине при выборе такого системного цвета для окна при изменении размеров перерисовка фона не происходит. Список системных цветов смотрите в [справке по структуре WNDCLASS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), либо в подключаемом файле `windows.inc` из masm32 (все, что начинается с `COLOR_`).

Чтобы указать конкретный цвет, можно создать "кисть" нужного цвета с помощью функции [CreateSolidBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (буквально, "создать сплошную кисть"). Её вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
invoke CreateSolidBrush, crColor
```

где rcColor - это [тройка цветов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) вида 00BBGGRRh, BB - голубая составляющая, GG - зелёная составляющая, RR - красная составляющая. Ярко-зелёный цвет будет кодироваться как 0000FF00h, более тусклый - как 00007F00h. Другие цвета получаются смешением трех основных, например желтый - это зелёный+красный (см. [модель RGB в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB)).

Для некоторых цветов в `windows.inc` есть свои константы для подстановки в функции создания кистей или карандашей:

```
Black                                equ 000000h
Blue                                 equ 0FF0000h
Green                                equ 00FF00h
Cyan                                 equ 0FFFF00h
Red                                  equ 0000FFh
Magenta                              equ 0FF00FFh
Yellow                               equ 00FFFFh
White                                equ 0FFFFFFh
Gray                                 equ 080808h
```

Поэтому, предварительно подключив `windows.inc`, можно создать кисть зелёного цвета таким вызовом:

```
invoke CreateSolidBrush, Green
```

Полученное значение (в регистре eax) нужно до регистрации класса записать в `wc.hbrBackground` (там где у вас `COLOR_BACKGROUND-1`).

Должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

[image: Зелёненькое окошко]

Для справки: кисти (brush) используются для заливки, карандаши (pen) - для обводки различных графических объектов. В данном случае создавалась сплошная (solid) кисть, но можно создавать заштриховывающие кисти, например.

> Я как понял COLOR_BACKGROUND-1 = белый, COLOR_BACKGROUND = серый, COLOR_BACKGROUND+1 = чёрный.

Не угадали. `COLOR_BACKGROUND` - это стандартный цвет фона окна, `COLOR_BACKGROUND+1 == COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION` - цвет заголовка активного окна, `COLOR_BACKGROUND-1 == COLOR_SCROLLBAR` - цвет сколлбара. Это системные цвета, они зависят от выбранной цветовой схемы Windows.